# Remove class from element if other with the same class is press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a site that looks like this:

[image: website look]

So, only one of the items under the same group (one group is type and the other is measure) can be clicked at the same time.

To keep the code as small as possible, I'll just add the code for the type group. The html is:

```
<div id="selector" class="btn-group">
    <h2>Measure</h2>
    <button type="button" name="Energy" class="btn-mark-measure">Energy</button>
    <button type="button" name="Demand" class="btn-mark-measure">Demand</button>
    <button type="button" name="Consume" class="btn-mark-measure">Consume</button>
    <button type="button" name="PF" class="btn-mark-measure">PF</button>
    <button type="button" name="Capacitive" class="btn-mark-measure">Capacitive</button>
    <button type="button" name="Inductive" class="btn-mark-measure">Inductive</button>
    <button type="button" name="PUE" class="btn-mark-measure">PUE</button>
</div>
```

And, I have a function that assign the name from the button press to a text field and keep the button as active.

```
<script>
    $('.btn-mark-type').click(function(){
        document.getElementById('type').value = this.name;
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass('active')
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active')
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now, what I want to do, it's apply .removeClass to all the elements but the one that the user just clicked. I assume that there will be a easy way to do it, I've been looking at google for a while, but I assume that I'm not looking for it properly.
Thanks!

Comment: define separate type class and measure class in html, then based on each apply your logic to remove active class then add active class. slight modification will be helpful , i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code.

- If you have multiple menus with different classnames for their menu items, it won't work since you are only looking for `btn-mark-type` and this class doesn't exists on your markup.
- If you have multiple menus, then clicking one item will deselect options from other menus since it removes `active` class from all menu items.

change it to something like

```
<script>
    bindToType ( "measure" );
    bindToType ( "type" );
    function bindToType( type )
    {
     $('.btn-mark-' + type ).click(function(){ //to ensure that different types have different bindings
         //remove only from  '.btn-mark-' + type, not from all .actives
         $('.btn-mark-' + type + '.active' ).removeClass( "active" );
         $( this ).addClass( 'active' );
     });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. My plan was to create a separate function to manage every state change and perform other stuff that I need to do. But, this way is much efficient.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to remove the class from all elements that currently have it, and then just add the class to the current element. To do so simply use something like:

```
$("btn").click(function(){
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

This will remove the `active` class from every element that has it (you can be more specific if those elements have some other classname as well just by updating `$(".active")` to `$(".desiredClass")`). And then will add the `active` class to the currently clicked button.

If you provide me with a jsFiddle, I might help you out with achieving what you want.

Hope this helps!